# Does this integral converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

WolframAlpha says that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \, dx \, dy \, dz$$
[converges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty+1%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E2+dz+dy+dx+), but it [cannot compute integrals that are more than three variables](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%201%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bw%5E2%29%5E2%20dz%20dy%20dx%20dw).

Does this integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)^2} \, dx \, dy \, dz \, dw$$
converge?

In general, does this integral
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac 1{(1+|x|^2)^2} \, dx$$
converge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to the spherical coordinates and integrate the angular part first. This will give you $(1+r^2)^2$ in the denominator and the area of the corresponding (hyper)sphere in the numerator (for the function is spherically symmetric). You don't really have to know the area, it suffices to know that it is $\sim r^{n-1}$. Clearly, 3 is the maximum dimension in which this converges.

Comment: This means $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac 1{(1+|x|^2)^{n-1}} \, dx$$ converges?

Comment: Surely it does, as long as $n>2$.

Comment: Though, I want to find an exponent that would make the integral converge for *all* $n$. Maybe if I change my exponent from $n-1$ to $n+1$, this will suffice, I hope...

Comment: That's right, it will. Even $n+1\over2$ will.

Comment: How do we know that the critical exponent for convergence is $\frac{n+1}2$?

Comment: It is not. It is $n\over2$, in that the integral diverges at this value, but converges at ${n\over2}+\varepsilon$ for any small $\varepsilon$.

Comment: See the answer by Jack D'Aurizio, it pretty much explains away the whole spherical coordinates thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the other answer doesn't help much. Again, I'm just looking for a proof of why $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac 1{(1+|x|^2)^s}$ for $s > \frac n2$. (Perhaps you know the proof since you stated yourself that the critical exponent is $\frac n2$.)

Comment: Why, that's obvious. ${r^{n-1}\over(1+r^2)^{n/2}}\sim{r^{n-1}\over r^n}={1\over r}$; is that integrable?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(R)$ be the measure of $\{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2=R^2\}$. It is obviously $S(1)\cdot R^{n-1}$.

On the other hand:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(1+\left|x\right|^2)^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{S(R)}{(1+R^2)^2}\,dR = S(1)\cdot\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{R^{n-1}}{(1+R^2)^2}\,dR$$
is convergent only for $n\leq 3$, and:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} = 4\pi\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}=\color{red}{\pi^2}.$$